# Update text of textblock in every sec in VB Net

Tags: vb.net, audio, timer, irrklang

I have a Sub, which handled when I create my new window. It loads and plays an mp3 file using Irrklang library. But how to update the playposition. I heard that i can use timer, but how to use it inside a sub?

```
Private Sub  MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    Dim Music = MyiSoundengine.Play2D("Music/001.mp3")

    I Want to update this in every sec!
    Dim Music_Playposition = Music.Playpostion

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a timer inside of a method/sub. The only way that a timer works is by periodically raising *events*; in the case of a timer, it's called the "Tick" event, raised each time that the timer "ticks".

You probably already know what events are—your `MainWindow_Loaded` method is handling one, the `Loaded` event of the `MainWindow` class.

So what you need to do is add a timer to your application, handle its Tick event, and inside that event handler update your textbox with the current position.

For example:

```
Public Class MainWindow

    Private WithEvents timer As New System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer()

    Public Sub New()
        ' Initialize the timer.
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);  ' "tick" every 1 second

        ' other code that goes in the constructor
        ' ...
    End Sub

    Private Sub timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timer.Tick
        ' TODO: Add code to update textbox with current position
    End Sub

    Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        ' Start the timer first.
        timer.Start()

        ' Then start playing your music.
        MyiSoundengine.Play2D("Music/001.mp3")
    End Sub

    ' any other code that you need inside of your MainWindow class
    ' ...

End Class
```

Note the use of the `WithEvents` keyword in the class-level declaration of the timer object. That makes it easy to handle its events using only `Handles` statements on the event handler. Otherwise, you have to use `AddHandler` inside of the constructor to wire up the event handler methods to the desired events.